# Create Address Book styled tableview for Edit/Add in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, addressbook

I want to create a **tableview same like as Address book of iPhone while Edit/Add contacts**.

**Is there any framework or popular control for this?**

**Help will be greatly appreciated.**

**Thanks for your time**

Comment: Address book framework is deprecated in ios 9

Comment: @user3182143, I knew this, I mean I needed a tableview same as contact app of iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen a particular framework to help with the UI, but [APAdressBook](https://github.com/Alterplay/APAddressBook) seems pretty useful in dealing with contact data.

The UI for the iOS address book should be fairly simple to re-create. For example, you could start with a [UISearchController](https://www.raywenderlich.com/113772/uisearchcontroller-tutorial) and then when you tap on a table view cell, you just push an individual contact view controller onto the stack.

There are also many native options for sending messages to these contacts, directly from your app, such as the [MessageUI Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MessageUI_Framework_Reference/). If you still want a framework to help you out more, there are plenty of UI components on Github.